What's the new keyframe protocol?
So it seems we're getting Blender updates that resemble android updates - nobody asked for them. Please enlighten me on how we go about keyframing multiple objects at once, with the same locrot or whatever. Is there a way to get back to the old way?


i is to keyframe with the default transform
Shiftk is to choose what are the default transforms
k is to keyframe with the desired transform (former i)


This video from Blender shows the new keyframe updates for Blender 4.1: https://youtu.be/bLojKyJx7fA
